# How does the list_add function for linux kernel linked lists work?

Tags: c, linked-list, linux-kernel

I've been trying to figure out how the `__list_add` function works in the linux kernel implementation of a linked list.

Here are the macros and data structures:

```c
#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) } /* Assign the next and prev pointers to itself */

#define LIST_HEAD(name) struct list_head name = LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)

struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

struct mystruct {
    int data ;
    struct list_head mylist;
};
```

Here is the function I am confused on.

```c
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head) { 
    __list_add(new, head, head->next); 
}

static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new, 
                  struct list_head *prev, 
                  struct list_head *next) { 
    next->prev = new; 
    new->next = next; 
    new->prev = prev; 
    prev->next = new; 
}
```

Here is the code I am trying to run.

```c
int main(void) {
    LIST_HEAD(mylinkedlist);
    struct mystruct first = {
                 .data = 10,
                 .mylist = LIST_HEAD_INIT(first.mylist)
    };
    list_add(&first.mylist,  &mylinkedlist);
    return 0;
}
```

So basically, I am just trying to add one element to this linked list. The part I am confused on is how it is passing the arguments through `__list_add` in the `list_add` function. I understand the first two arguments, `new` and `head`. However, why is `head->next` passed as the third argument? It doesn't make sense to me in the `__list_add` function in the first statement, `next->prev = new;`. Does this not mean that it is technically doing `(head->next)->prev = new`? Why you would get the `prev` of the `next` and assign it to `new`? I've tried drawing it out, but it doesn't add up. Wouldn't you simply want to do `head->prev = new`? Thanks.

Comment: Draw the generic case when you have many nodes already, and it may make more sense to you.

Comment: There are PLENTY descriptions of double linked lists in general and particularly in the Linux kernel. Have you tried to read some of them? E.g this first googled reference: https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/DataStructures/linux-datastructures-1.html. Among other things it describes `__list_add` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list with many members, each of them with a number corresponding to their desired position.

Let's say that you already have in the list members _3 and _5 (this member right now is in position 4, right next to _3, due to _4 not having been added yet), but you still haven't added member _4.

Now you want to insert `_4` just after member `_3` and before member `_5`.

`list_add(_4, _3);` will add the node in its correct place.

It will actually do `__list_add(_4, _3, _3->next);` which would evaluate to `__list_add(_4, _3, _5);`, which would then do the following:

```
_5->prev = _4;
_4->next = _5;
_4->prev = _3;
_3->next = _4;
```

I hope this is clear enough :)